# Convert tm of another timezone into tm of the GMT timezone

Tags: c++, timezone, c++20, c++-chrono

I'm using chrono and c++20.

I have a `tm` struct for EST timezone, but can't figure out how to obtain the corresponding time in the GMT zone.

Here is what I've been thinking:

```
tm timeInAmerica = {0};
timeInAmerica.tm_year = 75;//1975
timeInAmerica.tm_month = 0;//January
timeInAmerica.tm_mday = 31;
timeInAmerica.tm_hour = 23;
timeInAmerica.tm_minute = 23;
timeInAmerica.tm_second = 23;

auto timeZone = std::chrono::locate_zone("America/New_York");
auto sysTime = timeZone->to_sys( /*needs local_time */ );
```

...I don't know how to convert that `tm` into `local_time` so that I can feed it into `to_sys()`.

I also can't figure out how to convert the returned `sysTime` value back into `tm` (which will allow me to inspect the GMT year, month, day, hour, minute).

Comment: "*which will allow me to inspect the GMT year, month, day*" You can inspect these by converting the time into a `chrono::year_month_day`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thank you, I also want to maintain the hour, minute. I'll edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using namespace std::chrono;

tm timeInAmerica = {0};
timeInAmerica.tm_year = 75;//1975
timeInAmerica.tm_mon = 0;//January
timeInAmerica.tm_mday = 31;
timeInAmerica.tm_hour = 23;
timeInAmerica.tm_min = 23;
timeInAmerica.tm_sec = 23;

auto lt = local_days{year{timeInAmerica.tm_year+1900}
                    /month(timeInAmerica.tm_mon+1)
                    /timeInAmerica.tm_mday}
          + hours{timeInAmerica.tm_hour}
          + minutes{timeInAmerica.tm_min}
          + seconds{timeInAmerica.tm_sec};

auto timeZone = locate_zone("America/New_York");
auto sysTime = timeZone->to_sys(lt);

auto sysDay = floor<days>(sysTime);
year_month_day ymd = sysDay;
hh_mm_ss hms{sysTime - sysDay};

int y = int{ymd.year()};
int m = unsigned{ymd.month()};
int d = unsigned{ymd.day()};
int h = hms.hours().count();
int M = hms.minutes().count();
int s = hms.seconds().count();
```

I've issued a `using namespace std::chrono` just to keep the verbosity down to a low roar.  If you would prefer to put `std::chrono::` in all the right places, that's fine too.

`lt` is the `local_time<seconds>` (or just `local_seconds`) needed to represent the local time.  Careful on the biases (1900 and 1) when converting from a `tm`.

To convert `sysTime` back into a `{year, month, day, hour, minute, second}` structure, first truncate `sysTime` to a days-precision `time_point`.  Then that days-precision `time_point` can be converted to a `{year, month, day}` data structure.

The time of day is simply the date_time minus the date.  This can be converted into an `{hours, minutes, seconds}` data structure: `hh_mm_ss`.

Both `year_month_day` and `hh_mm_ss` have getters to get the strongly typed fields.  And then each strongly typed field has conversions to integral as shown above.  When converting back to a `tm`, don't forget about the biases (1900 and 1).

Additionally, everything has a streaming operator.  This makes it very convenient for debugging:

```
cout << "lt      = " << lt << '\n';       // 1975-01-31 23:23:23
cout << "sysTime = " << sysTime << '\n';  // 1975-02-01 04:23:23
cout << "sysDay  = " << sysDay << '\n';   // 1975-02-01
cout << "ymd     = " << ymd << '\n';      // 1975-02-01
cout << "hms     = " << hms << '\n';      // 04:23:23
```